# Add line in textGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a line to my textGrob. I  am not sure how to go about it and if it is possible. This is the desired outcome:

Here is the code for the text part. Any help to achieve the first part will be appreciated.

```
textGrob("
A: Method One
B: Method Two ")
```

[image: Desired outcome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a line as part of a pure textGrob unless you emulate it with underscores or long Unicode dashes (`"\u2014"`):

```
grid::grid.newpage()
tg <- grid::textGrob("\U2014\u2014 Observed median\nA: Method One\nB: Method Two",
                     x = 0.15,  hjust = 0, gp = gpar(cex = 4))
grid::grid.draw(tg)
```

[image]

If you want an actual line, simply add in a lineGrob. You can even combine a lineGrob and textGrob into a single grob:

```
tg <- grid::textGrob("        Observed median\nA: Method One\nB: Method Two",
                     x = 0.15,  hjust = 0, gp = gpar(cex = 4))
lg <- grid::linesGrob(unit(c(0.15, 0.28), "npc"), unit(c(0.63, 0.63), "npc"), 
                      gp = gpar(lwd = 8))
combo <- grid::grobTree(tg, lg)
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(combo)
```

[image]

This is probably closer to what you wanted, but the long dash hack is a bit easier.

Comment: Thank you so much @Allan Cameron. You are a lifesaver. This is exactly what I wanted. I will look into the long Unicode dashes since I need to add different linetypes.